# List element hightlight?

Tags: android

I have a list and when I do setOnClickListener for an Item I don't have highlight on Items in a List.

That is not expected behavior because I want to give user a way to see which item was selected on touch.

Is there some way to make it highlighted?

tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try to set color to your list item xml. Define your list item color depending on the state. Try [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) out.